# How to have my GoDaddy hosted domain name take me directly and automatically to my blog

Tags: links, blog, godaddy

I have a website on GoDaddy. I have WordPress downloaded on a directory called `blog`.

I would like so that when some one types my website name it takes it to the blog, but at the moment I have to type `/blog` at the end of it.

Is what I want possible, if so how do I do it?

Comment: What is the web server?? Apache, IIS, Nginx? It makes a difference in how to answer this question. Of course, you could just remove WP and reinstall it to work in the root directory. That would be what I would do. It would be a lot cleaner in the end.

Comment: I know its a linux server. I have considered a reinstall. main reason is that I like to stay organized and would like to have blog aspect of my website in folder. Also i will continue to look into the server but not really sure where to look for that

Comment: It is okay to have it in a blog directory. I would then just create a website rather than redirecting... however, a redirect would be wise for the short term. If you have Apache, you would see the directory /etc/apache2/ which is where it is typically installed, though some packages install it in other places.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either move it from the directory as mentioned, or you can keep it in the directory and have it appear in the root by doing a bit of tweaking as follows:

1. Go to the General panel.
2. In the box for Site address (URL): change the address to the root directory's URL. Example: `http://example.com`.
3. Click Save Changes. (Do not worry about the error message and do not try to see your blog at this point! You will probably get a message about file not found.)
4. Copy (NOT MOVE!) the `index.php` and *.htaccess* files from the WordPress directory into the root directory of your site—the latter is probably named something like `www` or `public_html`. The *.htaccess* file is invisible, so you may have to set your FTP client to show hidden files. If you are not using pretty permalinks, then you may not have a *.htaccess* file. If you are running WordPress on a Windows (IIS) server and are using pretty permalinks, you'll have a *web.config* rather than a *.htaccess* file in your WordPress directory.
5. Edit your root directory's `index.php`.

   1. Open your root directory's `index.php` file in a text editor
   2. Change the line that says:
      `require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wp-blog-header.php' );`
      to the following, using your directory name for the WordPress core files:
      `require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wordpress/wp-blog-header.php' );`
6. Save the file.
7. Login to your site (if you aren't still already). The URL should still be `http://example.com/wordpress/wp-admin/`
8. If you have set up Permalinks, go to the Permalinks panel and update your Permalink structure. WordPress will automatically update your *.htaccess* file if it has the appropriate file permissions. If WordPress can't write to your *.htaccess* file, it will display the new rewrite rules to you, which you should manually copy into your *.htaccess* file (in the same directory as the main `index.php` file.)

More info here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory